# Reset Leaflet Map Choropleth on Zoom in and put it back on zoom out

Tags: javascript, leaflet

Not sure if anyone is familiar with this leaflet map on the leaflet site found here:
http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth.html 
It is a really cool map, just one thing. Is there a way to get the choropleth to disappear upon a certain zoom level? I know you can use map.getZoom() to detect zoom level. Essentially, I am trying to reset the styles that are invoked on page load within the function getColor(d). 
Not sure how though. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`L.geoJson(statesData)` returns an object with the method `removeLayer`. If you pass that object to a variable (let's just call it data) and call an anonymous function on `zoomend` you can capture the map's zoom level with `map.getZoom()`, you can match it to any arbitrary zoom level and then call `data.removeLayer()`.

If you open up dev tools (aka your web inspector) in your browser and input the following line into your JavaScript console, you'll be able to see more methods and information that's fired whenever you zoom in and out of the map.

```
map.on('zoomend', function(e) { console.log(e); })
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply. Unfortunately, that seems to remove that map layer in the background and not the actual choropleth in the foreground. I am actually trying to remove the choropleth or re-draw the map at certain zoom levels. I may not have been clear enough in my question, my apologies for that.

Comment: Here is a snipit of my code: map.on('viewreset', function(){ if(map.getZoom() > 4){             
             //Draw Choropleth
        }else{ // Re-draw map } });

Comment: Thanks. Could you please share more of your code so I can better diagnose and debug? You can use [Github's gists](https://gist.github.com/) without an account.

Comment: I actually found a solution here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41928/adding-removing-leaflet-geojson-layers

Comment: It involved my understanding the use of geojson layers:  if(map.getZoom() >= 5){             
                 map.removeLayer(geojson);
            } <br /> Thanks so much for your help on this all who contributed.